# Unable to publish to local maven repo when using Gradle and Spring Boot

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a very simple spring-boot (1.0.2) example (based on http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) using Gradle (1.12) to create a jar file.

I'm trying to build and publish to my local maven repo using either the maven or maven-publish gradle plugins but am getting the error:

> Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Failed to validate POM for project ngdc.sample:hello-springboot at /Users/jcc/Documents/stash/hello-springboot/build/poms/pom-default.xml

and don't understand why. version, group, and archivesBaseName are all specified in the build.gradle.  A similar project which doesn't rely on SpringBoot works fine.

Can someone suggest what the problem might be?

Thanks!

--john

Comment: `artifactory` plugin requires `maven` plugin, and `artifactory-publish` requires `maven-publish` plugin and from your question it looks like `spring-boot` plugin conflicts with them. So, probably you need to start with figuring out that.
It might be a good idea to rephrase the question or ask additional one regarding the adding of maven plugins to spring-boot probject.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might need to ensure that the parent pom or dependency management is specified as well (depends on your configuration, but if you are using the Spring Boot Gradle plugin you probably do need it). Example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-integration-tests/spring-boot-gradle-tests/src/test/resources/installer.gradle

```
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.project {
          parent { 
            groupId 'org.springframework.boot'
            artifactId 'spring-boot-starter-parent'
            version "${project.bootVersion}"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had this exact same problem and this fixed it. I had to hardcode the ${project.bootVersion} though.

Comment: Why do we need so strange configuration. I try to set `pom.project.parent` to my project and it failed. So I copy your solution and it's worked.

Comment: What should we change if we use maven-publish plugin? Code snippet above doesn't work in such case.

Comment: @ernesto.guevara I made progress on this issue with the maven-publish plugin using:     publications {
        mavenJar(MavenPublication){
            pom.withXml {
                def parentNode = asNode().appendNode('parent')
                parentNode.appendNode('groupId','org.springframework.boot')
                parentNode.appendNode('artifactId','spring-boot-starter-parent')
                parentNode.appendNode('version',springBootVersion)
            }

            from components.java
        }
    }

Comment: Thanx a lot for the solution, just the thing I was looking for. In addition, I've extended the build script with `install.depensOn build` for the published jar to be runnable.

Answer (score 1):

When the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin without dependency versions in the `dependency{...}` section, the pom is generated without version for Spring Boot etc.

So at the moment it's required to create the relation to the parent pom by yourself for all maven realted tasks
`parent { 
  groupId 'org.springframework.boot'
  artifactId 'spring-boot-starter-parent'
  version "${project.bootVersion}"
}`

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1716

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem here. Thanks @cjstehno, and I will summary my build file here.

1) if you're using maven plugin, the official guide is available for this.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-publishing-artifacts-to-a-maven-repository

2) if you're using maven-publish plugin, you can follow scripts below.

Also, because spring boot needs its own package procedure before publish (such as bootRepackage and assemble), So I make publish depends on build task.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.9.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = '<some group id>'
version = '<some version with -SNAPSHOT>'

jar {
    baseName = '<jar base name>'
}

publish.dependsOn build

publishing {
    publications { 
        mavenJar(MavenPublication){ 
            pom.withXml { 
                def parentNode = asNode().appendNode('parent') 
                parentNode.appendNode('groupId','org.springframework.boot') 
                parentNode.appendNode('artifactId','spring-boot-starter-parent') 
                parentNode.appendNode('version','1.1.9.RELEASE') 
            } 
            from components.java 
        } 
    }
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'admin'
                password 'admin123'
            }
            url "http://<nexus server>:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This tells me your artifact (jar or war) is being created but the validation of the accompanying pom is failing. For a valid maven artifact you need `groupdId`, `artifactId` and `version`....
Which translate to gradle `group`, `archivesBaseName` and `version`.
Make sure you have these three properties set or configured on your artifact and you might get some luck :-)

e.g...
archivesBaseName = 'xcxcxcxc'
group = "com.blah.xxdddd"
version = '#.#.#'
...