# spring io platform using versionManagement gradle maven publish fails

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-io

Using the Spring io platform with Gradle, publish tasks fail with validation errors on generated pom. It seems the Gradle publish tasks both uploadArchives and Maven publishing expect version numbers to be in the generated pom. When using the Spring gradle plugin to manage dependency versions the generated pom does not contain any version numbers and hence fails validation. To test this I created a new project based on the simple Gradle sample in STS. I then changed the build.gradle file as follows

```
buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    versionManagement 'io.spring.platform:platform-versions:1.0.0.RELEASE@properties'
    compile 'commons-collections:commons-collections'
}

group = 'someGroup'
organization = 'FooInc'

uploadArchives {
    repositories { mavenDeployer { repository(url: "file:c:/gradle/myRepo/") } }
}
```

Running the Gradle uploadArchives task results in the exception

```
  * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
    > Could not publish configuration 'archives'
       > Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Failed to validate POM for project someGroup:Foo at C:\Users\Test\Foo\build\poms\pom-default.xml

    * Try:

Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:58)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Could not publish configuration 'archives'
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Failed to validate POM for project someGroup:Foo at C:\Users\Test\Foo\build\poms\pom-default.xml
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.Pom.initialiseMavenProject(Pom.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.initializePom(AbstractArtifactTask.java:527)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.InstallDeployTaskSupport.initializePom(InstallDeployTaskSupport.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DeployTask.doExecute(DeployTask.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.CustomDeployTask.doExecute(CustomDeployTask.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.execute(AbstractArtifactTask.java:751)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.AbstractMavenResolver.execute(AbstractMavenResolver.java:212)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:203)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:181)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.publish(DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$3.transform(Transformers.java:131)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.publish(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:67)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: Failed to validate POM for project someGroup:Foo at C:\Users\Test\Foo\build\poms\pom-default.xml
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.processProjectLogic(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1077)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:880)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:508)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.Pom.initialiseMavenProject(Pom.java:211)
        ... 70 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.815 secs

C:\Users\Test\Foo>gradlew --stacktrace clean uploadArchives
```

If I change the build file to explicitly add the version the upload is fine.

Comment: I am also having this problem, but have not found a solution other than explicitly adding a version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to publish to local maven repo when using Gradle and Spring Boot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665976/unable-to-publish-to-local-maven-repo-when-using-gradle-and-spring-boot)