# Artifact not found during install task with Gradle, Spring Boot plugin and Nexus

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, nexus

On a **Gradle** project using **Spring Boot plugin**, and **Nexus** repo manager, I encounter an `ArtifactNotFoundException` during `install` task.

To give some more explanations, as explained in thread [Unable to publish to local maven repo when using Gradle and Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665976/unable-to-publish-to-local-maven-repo-when-using-gradle-and-spring-boot), to avoid a Spring Boot bug, I added the relation with the `spring-boot-started-parent` pom in the install task.

Doing so, I face the following stacktrace:

```
$ gradle install --stacktrace
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:installDownloading: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom from repository central at http://central
Error transferring file: central
Downloading: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':install'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Cannot find parent: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent for project: com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6 for project com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':install'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:296)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:148)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:105)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:85)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:184)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Could not publish configuration 'archives'
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:570)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:553)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Cannot find parent: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent for project: com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6 for project com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.Pom.initialiseMavenProject(Pom.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.initializePom(AbstractArtifactTask.java:527)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.InstallDeployTaskSupport.initializePom(InstallDeployTaskSupport.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.InstallTask.doExecute(InstallTask.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.CustomInstallTask.doExecute(CustomInstallTask.java:34)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.execute(AbstractArtifactTask.java:751)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.AbstractMavenResolver.execute(AbstractMavenResolver.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:102)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.publish(DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$3.transform(Transformers.java:131)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.publish(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:64)
        ... 74 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Cannot find parent: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent for project: com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6 for project com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1396)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:823)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:508)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.Pom.initialiseMavenProject(Pom.java:211)
        ... 90 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: POM 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:605)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1392)
        ... 94 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)


        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:228)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:558)
        ... 95 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:404)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        ... 97 more
```

When using the `--debug`, I also find:

```
11:10:30.612 [ERROR] [system.err] Downloading: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom from repository central at http://central
11:10:32.887 [ERROR] [system.err] Error transferring file: central
11:10:32.888 [INFO] [system.out] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE' from repository central (http://central): Error transferring file: central
11:10:32.889 [ERROR] [system.err] Downloading: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
11:10:35.152 [ERROR] [system.err] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
11:10:35.153 [INFO] [system.out] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
11:10:35.156 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
 Diagnosis:

Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Cannot find parent: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent for project: com.toto:myproject:jar:1.0.6 for project com.toto:myproject:jar:1.0.6
Unable to download the artifact from any repository
```

At first sight, the error seems easy to understand: artifact (`spring-boot-starter-parent`) not found on Nexus.
**The problem is my Nexus is configured to access Maven Central to get the dependencies if not hosted**.

I checked that my group, artifact ID and version were correct (`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE`).
No problem on that point, I can find this dependency on Maven Central site.

To check if the problem could come from the way the `spring-boot-starter-parent` is declared (in the install task, and not in a `dependencies` section), I created a very simple Maven project, with the following `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>toto</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-test-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Draft project</name>

</project>
```

No problem with this project and its pom, the spring-boot-starter-parent is retrieved, and **added to the Nexus storage of the proxy repo** targeting Maven Central:

[image]

That was **NOT the case with Gradle**, which makes me think that this problem is Gradle specific.

<s>As a workaround, **if I host the artifact in Nexus, the Gradle build works fine**.</s>
As a workaround, if the dependency is present in my local repo, the Gradle build works fine.
But, if someone has some clue on how to solve the issue, it would allow me not to manually add a version of the dependency at each new release.

---

**EDIT 20150415**

To help the understanding of the issue, here is my `build.gradle`:

```
// Declare elements required by the build itself
buildscript {

    project.ext {
        bootVersion = '1.2.3.RELEASE'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
      maven {
         url 'http://mynexus.net.intra:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/'
         credentials {
            username 'someUsername'
            password 'somePassword'
         }
      }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${project.bootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
targetCompatibility = 1.8
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

// To configure the Maven plugin
project.group = 'com.mygroup'
// If project.version is not set, artifactId is taken by default, from folder name
project.version = '1.0.6'

// required to install the jar on local Maven repo, when using the Spring Boot plugin 
// check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665976/unable-to-publish-to-local-maven-repo-when-using-gradle-and-spring-boot
// !!!! Careful !!!! You could be forced to manually add the dependency declared in this section in your local repo, to have the script work 
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.project {
          parent {
            groupId 'org.springframework.boot'
            artifactId 'spring-boot-starter-parent'
            version "${project.bootVersion}"
          }
        }
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'myjar'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
  maven {
    url 'http://mynexus.fr.net.intra:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/'
    credentials {
      username 'someUsername'
      password 'somePassword'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager")
    compile("oracle:ojdbc6:12.1.0.1")

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'conf/java'
        }
    }
}
```

To answer several comments, and to check that my Nexus was well declared, **I deleted the `ojdbc6` from my local repo and from Gradle cache**, then I relaunched a `gradle install`.
Here are the logs:

```
$ gradle clean install
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: http://gradle.org/docs/2.0/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
:clean
:compileJava
Download http://mynexus.fr.net.intra:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/oracle/ojdbc6/12.1.0.1/ojdbc6-12.1.0.1.jar
:processResources
:classes
:jar
:installDownloading: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom from repository central at http://central
Error transferring file: central
Downloading: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':install'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Cannot find parent: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent for project: com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6 for project com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.268 secs
```

As can be seen for the ojdbc6 dependency, **the Nexus is used to resolve it**.
It now seems to me that my Nexus declaration is not taken into account inside the **install task definition**.
I am going to search a way to readd this declaration in this section.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Do you have direct access to Maven Central, or is it blocked with everything being routed through Nexus? AFAIK, when Gradle validates a generated pom file, everything that's referenced by the pom must be available from Maven Central. If an artifact isn't in Maven Central, or access to Maven Central is restricted, the validation will fail.

Comment: How do you have configured your Nexus instance in your Gradle script? Remember that Gradle doesn't use the Maven settings.xml, so you have to configure your Nexus in the Gradle build or init script.

Answer (score 1):

I made some more investigations, and I am now rather convinced that this issue comes from a **bug in Gradle `install` task**.

First, here is the Nexus configuration in my Maven `settings.xml`:

```
[...]
<mirrors>

    <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://mynexus.net.intra:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </mirror>

[...]
</mirrors>

[...]
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <!-- Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
        <!-- all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>

    [...]
</profiles>

[...]
```

Now, here is my classic issue in `install task`, using `--debug` option:

```
14:11:38.995 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':install'
14:11:38.996 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':install' is up-to-date
14:11:38.998 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Executing task ':install' (up-to-date check took 0.002 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
14:11:38.999 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':install'.
14:11:39.000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Publishing configuration: configuration ':archives'
14:11:39.005 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher] Publishing to org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.BaseMavenInstaller@71a6c033
14:11:39.034 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Adding reference: ant.PropertyHelper
14:11:39.035 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Detected Java version: 1.8 in: C:\tools\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre
14:11:39.035 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Detected OS: Windows 7
14:11:39.044 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Adding reference: ant.ComponentHelper
14:11:39.048 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Project base dir set to: C:\workspace\myjar
14:11:39.084 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Maven Ant Tasks version: 2.1.3
14:11:39.088 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\Users\536355\.m2\settings.xml
14:11:39.129 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\workspace\maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml
14:11:39.257 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Adding reference: org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer
14:11:39.318 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\Users\536355\.m2\settings.xml
14:11:39.320 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\workspace\maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml
14:11:39.345 [ERROR] [system.err] Downloading: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom from repository central at http://central
14:11:41.623 [ERROR] [system.err] Error transferring file: central
14:11:41.623 [INFO] [system.out] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE' from repository central (http://central): Error transferring file: central
14:11:41.624 [ERROR] [system.err] Downloading: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
14:11:43.894 [ERROR] [system.err] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
14:11:43.895 [INFO] [system.out] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
14:11:43.897 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
 Diagnosis:

Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Cannot find parent: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent for project: com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6 for project com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6
Unable to download the artifact from any repository


14:11:43.898 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':install'
```

We see that Gradle tries first to get the dependency from `http://central`, then from `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` (the usual Maven Central).

If I change my Maven `settings.xml`, modifying the URL of the central repository from `http://central` to `http://toto`, the logs become:

```
11:21:29.746 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':install' is up-to-date
11:21:29.747 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Executing task ':install' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
11:21:29.748 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':install'.
11:21:29.749 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Publishing configuration: configuration ':archives'
11:21:29.757 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher] Publishing to org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.BaseMavenInstaller@3bd6b327
11:21:29.783 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Adding reference: ant.PropertyHelper
11:21:29.784 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Detected Java version: 1.8 in: C:\tools\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre
11:21:29.784 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Detected OS: Windows 7
11:21:29.794 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Adding reference: ant.ComponentHelper
11:21:29.797 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Project base dir set to: C:\workspace\myjar
11:21:29.830 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Maven Ant Tasks version: 2.1.3
11:21:29.833 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\Users\536355\.m2\settings.xml
11:21:29.873 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\workspace\maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml
11:21:29.992 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Adding reference: org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer
11:21:30.048 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\Users\536355\.m2\settings.xml
11:21:30.051 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\workspace\maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml
11:21:30.075 [ERROR] [system.err] Downloading: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom from repository central at http://toto
11:21:30.088 [ERROR] [system.err] Error transferring file: toto
11:21:30.089 [INFO] [system.out] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE' from repository central (http://toto): Error transferring file: toto
11:21:30.090 [ERROR] [system.err] Downloading: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
11:21:32.354 [ERROR] [system.err] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
11:21:32.355 [INFO] [system.out] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
11:21:32.357 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
 Diagnosis:

Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Cannot find parent: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent for project: com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6 for project com.mygroup:myjar:jar:1.0.6
Unable to download the artifact from any repository


11:21:32.358 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':install'
```

As can be seen, Gradle now tries first to get the dependency from `http://toto`, then it still goes to Maven Central.
This implies that Gradle:

- effectively reads my Maven `settings.xml`
- but **can't access, in the install task, to the Maven mirror definition**

For me, **the main problem is here**.

Finally, **if I now add the `spring-boot-starter-parent` dependency to my maven local repository**, the logs become:

```
14:14:08.474 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':install'
14:14:08.474 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':install' is up-to-date
14:14:08.475 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Executing task ':install' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
14:14:08.475 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':install'.
14:14:08.476 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Publishing configuration: configuration ':archives'
14:14:08.481 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher] Publishing to org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.BaseMavenInstaller@74eaee53
14:14:08.504 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Adding reference: ant.PropertyHelper
14:14:08.504 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Detected Java version: 1.8 in: C:\tools\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre
14:14:08.505 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Detected OS: Windows 7
14:14:08.515 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Adding reference: ant.ComponentHelper
14:14:08.519 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Project base dir set to: C:\workspace\myjar
14:14:08.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Maven Ant Tasks version: 2.1.3
14:14:08.558 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\Users\536355\.m2\settings.xml
14:14:08.599 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\workspace\maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml
14:14:08.725 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Adding reference: org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer
14:14:08.798 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\Users\536355\.m2\settings.xml
14:14:08.800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\workspace\maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml
14:14:08.892 [INFO] [system.out] [INFO] Installing C:\workspace\myjar\target\libs\myjar-1.0.6.jar to C:\workspace\maven-3.0.4\repository\com\mygroup\myjar\1.0.6\myjar-1.0.6.jar
14:14:08.905 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':install'
```

In this case the build is successful.

So, from those clues, **I would suggest that there is a bug in Gradle install task**, badly taking into account the repo configuration in Maven `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Your project configuration does NOT actually talk to Nexus. It seems like the Gradle task is farming out to Maven and it in turn is not configured via a settings.xml to connect to the Nexus public group but rather still tries to access the Central Repository directly.

You probably have to configure Maven and maybe also Gradle to connect to Nexus. Details for both can be found [in the Nexus documentation about configuring build tools.](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config.html)

Comment: Gradle doesn't use Maven to resolve dependencies from Maven repositories, it uses Ivy under the hood. So the Maven settings.xml etc. doesn't affect the Gradle build.

Comment: I am aware of that but there are a bunch of bugs in Gradle where it falls back to reading the settings.xml. In any case.. the chapter also details the config for Gradle. Also it might still be using Maven in the spring boot tools which is why I linked to it all.

Comment: I'd rather suspect that he hasn't configured Gradle to fetch the dependencies from his Nexus instance (otherwise it would appear in the logfile).

Comment: Unfortunately, **I do have configured Gradle to use my Nexus instance**.  Other dependencies are effectively taken from Nexus. I am going to edit my question to add my buid.gradle and some more logs.  In fact, it seems to me that **my Nexus declaration is NOT taken into account for my customization of the `install` task**.

Answer (score 0):

For me helped switching from gradle 2.2 to 2.9.

Which version did you use?

Also after switching to spring boot 1.3.0 i didn't need this block anymore

```
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.project {
          parent {
            groupId 'org.springframework.boot'
            artifactId 'spring-boot-starter-parent'
            version "${project.bootVersion}"
          }
        }
    }
}
```